# searching about specific word in a Directory then delete it

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I search in a directory for a given word in text files by this shell script instruction

```
 grep -r "$2" "$1"
```

- `$2` is the directory
- `$1` is the word

How can I delete this word after it?

Comment: You syntax is not right, the pattern should always come before the name of the file(s)(or directory(ies))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gawk` to do this:

```
gawk -i inplace '{gsub("test", "");print}' file.txt
```

Here "test" is the word you are trying to delete and file.txt is the file you are trying to edit. You already find this using grep hence, I am not including that part.

I am editing this on the suggestion of @Serg

```
echo -n "Enter the path to directory (/path/to/dir), followed by [enter]:"
read dir_path

echo -n "Enter the word you are looking for, followed by [enter]:"
read word

cd ${dir_path}

for file in "$dir_path"/*txt; do
    echo $file

    awk -v var=$word -i inplace '{gsub(var, "");print}' $file
done
```

Comment: Yes . . . .but you're looking at just one file here. OK wants to search through multiple ones. How do you do that ?

Comment: Well I can always put the above thing in a loop and replace the word and the input file with variables.

Comment: Very well . . . so why not add that to your answer ?

Comment: @Serd, I have added the whole shell script. Let me know if this is what you were asking me to do.

Comment: Yup, that will do. Although it could be done simpler, but this would work. Have an upvote !

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is line *matching tool*. It only finds lines that have a word and is not intended for text editing/processing.

`sed` however, is the right tool for that.  Typically you'd use substitution to delete a word, like so:

```
sed 's/word//g' text.txt
```

For multiple files in  the same directory one can use the wildcard:

```
sed  's/word//g' *
```

The `-i` inplace flag is necessary to actually make changes to a file.

Here's a working example:

```
$> echo "HELLO WORLD" | tee {one,two,three}.txt                                
HELLO WORLD
$> sed -i 's/WORLD//g' *                                                       
$> cat one.txt
HELLO 
$> cat two.txt                                                                 
HELLO 
$>
```

Small disadvantage of this approach is that you are performing the operation on all of the files being searched. How do we take care of just one exact file ? Well, we can use `grep` to tell us the filename that has the `word` with `-l` option, and then pass it on to `sed` using `xargs`.

Here is a working example.

```
$> echo "HELLO BEAUTIFUL WORLD" > one.txt                                      
$> grep -l 'BEAUTIFUL'  *  
one.txt
$> grep -l 'BEAUTIFUL'  * | xargs sed -i 's/WORLD//g'                          
$> cat one.txt
HELLO BEAUTIFUL 
$>
```